# File ownership changes when uploading files to a Apache server using WebDAV

Tags: webdav, ownership

I have a webdav share set up on a server at my house. When accessing this server with my authenticated username from my iPhone webdav client and uploading files, the files are owned by `www-data:www-dat`a which is what I expect, since that's the user that runs Apache.

However when I access the share with my laptop (Running Ubuntu Gnome) through the Nautilus file browser, the files I create end up with my username and group for my laptop's user (`mordecai:mordecai`) which doesn't make sense to me, since I'm using the same protocol and user-password credentials on both systems. This causes problems because I can't alter files that I upload with one device with the other device.

I want to be able to upload things while I'm out and about, and be able to rsync my laptop when I'm working, and then be able to open the files from my phone later, and this is preventing that.

Comment: `-rw-rw----. 1 www-data www-data  46K Jul 23 14:35 BlackMagicDarkMild.pdf
-rw-rw----. 1 mordecai mordecai 674K Jul 23 14:25 MicroBru_Liberty_Cream_Ale_Recipe.pdf
    -rw-rw----. 1 www-data www-data 178K Jul 23 14:35 WhiteHouseHoneyPorter.pdf`
Here's an example of the ownership after uploading two different files from the two different devices. As you can see there is a disparity of ownership occurring when I upload from my laptop. The file owned by mordecai:mordecai was uploaded from my laptop. The others were from my phone.

Comment: These lines were taken from the `ls -lah` output on the server in the webdav directory.

Comment: Does the user mordecai actually exist on your server? You could check with `awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd`. Also could it be possible that you transferred these files with anything other than webDAV? such as FTP? Because this is one of the issues that webDAV tries to solve.

Answer (score 1):

That you see your own username and group in Nautilus on your Ubuntu laptop is working as intended. This is only locally, these permissions are not carried over to the webDAV server. As per the man page of davfs2:

```
   FILE OWNER AND PERMISSIONS

   davfs2  implements  Unix  permissions  for access control. But changing
   owner and permissions of a file is only local.  It  is  intended  as  a
   means for the owner of the file system, to control whether other local
   users may access this file system.

   The server does not know about this. From the  servers  point  of  view
   there  is  just  one  user  (identified  by the credentials) connected.
   Another WebDAV-client, connected to the same server, is not affected by
   this local changes.
```

Maybe you could elaborate on the issues you are facing, because it's not due to the file ownership being set to your local user.

Comment: I appended an explanation to my original question so that it's more clear. The problem does appear to be ownership based, but I can't seem to find any way to control the ownership of files created over webdav. They should, in a perfect world, both be `www-data:www-data` because they are being created essentially the same way from my understanding of this.